# Access JSON parse and save in object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, fetch

I am trying to access certain objects that are inside a parsed JSON and stored inside an object. In this case data.json

```
var data = {
    json: '',
    text: '',
    welcome: '',
    q1: '',
}

let foo = await fetch(spreadsheet);
data.text = await foo.text();
data.json = JSON.parse(data.text.substr(47).slice(0, -2))
data.welcome = data.json.table.rows[2]
console.log(data.welcome)
```

I don't know how to access each of them to be able to save them in the object I have.

Here is the parse JSON:

```
{
  c: [
    null,
    { v: '2. Pagos' },
    {
      v: '1. Mi pago no concuerda. (Recuerda que el reporte debe estar dentro de la fecha especificada)'
    },
    { v: 'Link Formulario' },
    { v: 'https://forms.gle/jBnmFyHCCBePN9Ws5' },
    null,
    { v: null }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this:

```
JSON.parse(data.text.substr(47).slice(0, -2))
```

works fine, this:

```
console.log(data.json.c[1].v)
```

should print:

> 2. Pagos